# Display sql data in datagrid view having predefined columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagrid

[image: My Win Form]

[image: My Database]

I want the sql data to be displayed in the data grid predefined columns when id(in database) is entered in the PID(textbox). for example: if I enter 1 in textbox, the product_Name(wai wai chicken) should display in the column Particulars, the product_Id(1) should itself display in the column PID, actual_Sp(15) should display in the column Amount and also when number is entered in Qty textbox it should display in Unit Qty column and should be multiplied with amount (say when 1 is entered wai wai is displayed as well as 15(actual_sp) is displayed in amount when 2 is entered in qty textbox the amount should display 30(as 15*2=30)).

I have tried the following code but it is adding new columns in my DGV instead of displaying in my predefined columns:

```
string cc = "";
        int n;
        if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out n))
        {
            cc = "product_Id = " + textBox1.Text.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            cc = "product_Name LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'";
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            cc = "1 = 1";
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SUMIT;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select product_Name as [Product Name],cast(actual_Sp as INT) * '" + textBox2.Text + " 'as [Actual SP] from Product WHERE " + cc, con); ;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
       dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 7;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ProductId";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "PID";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "product_Id";

        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "S.N.";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Serial Number";

        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Particulars";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Particulars";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "product_Name";


        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Unit Quantity";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Unit Quantity";

        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Amount";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Amount";

        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Discount";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Discount";

        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Sub-Total";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Sub-Total";     
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Can you show your front end code (asp.net webforms?).

Comment: @sr28 m not using(asp.net web), its c#(win form)

Comment: you could make a list view instead. With a listview you can customize the grid better than with a gridview.

Comment: Looks like you need to DataBind the columns in your DGV to the SQL columns you want them to contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you.

```
SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
                    "Select product_Name as [Product Name],
                            actual_Sp as [Actual SP] from Product WHERE " + cc, con);
```

with

```
SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
                    "Select product_Name as [Product Name], 
                            actual_Sp * " + TxtQty.Text + " as [Actual SP] 
                            from Product WHERE " + cc, con);
```

This will do the multiplication of the `actual_Sp` for the number of quantity you add to the TextBox

Comment: when I debug It displays error converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: To run this query `actual_Sp` should be numeric type instead of varchar. BTW you can try `cast(actual_Sp as INT) * " + TxtQty.Text + "`

Comment: actual_Sp is of type numeric but still its showing error

Comment: now its showing ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control error. I've edited the  code I've posted please go through it once again..